# Android: Call listener manually from java code

Tags: android, call, listener

Is there any way to call a listener manually from code?

More background information: I use a Spinner and a DatePicker. With the Spinner you can choose a reason for staying at home (maybe your ill, maybe you have vacation) and with the DatePicker you can choose the date how long you will not be available. With these two pieces of information I build up a string for a TextView and show the same data in a compact way. The building process for the string is set by some listeners which recognize changes on one of the two controls and build and set up the new string. 
If I start the program and read some data from a server the string will not be build (clearly because nothing changed and no listener will called).

The workaround is to build the string in my own `onLoaddata()` method. But I think it would be smoother way to call one listener to build the string for me. I also can "call" a listener if I just do some fake `.updateDate` but I don't think it’s a good idea to create useless calls...

Maybe someone of you have a good hint for me?

Comment: Your own method to load data is the best option - the code would be clearer.

Comment: Of course the code will be clearer, but I have to write the same code again (and I don’t like to write the same code twice or more if it isn’t necessary), I don’t want to discuss about the workarounds because they are working without problems, I want to know if there is a way to call the listener!

Comment: You don't need to write the same code twice - use one method to update your TextView and call it from any place you want, whether it is listener's callback or onCreate(..)

Comment: Hmm… I think I don’t know what you mean exactly. Update the TextView happens in a listener, no extra method. You mean I should create an extra method inside the listener class like `onUpdateTextView` to set the text and call this method in my `onLoadData`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following **pattern**:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ...

        // Some initialization here
        findViewById(R.id.some_button).setOnClickListener(this);

        ...

        // Here you want to update your view
        updateTextView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.some_button:
            // Here you also want to update your view
            updateTextView();
            break;

        ...

        }
    }

    private void updateTextView() {
        // Here you update your view
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you work, but how I already mentioned before I search for a way to call the listener. I know that I can just create a method in my activity and call it form the listener, that’s also a workaround. I don’t want to discuss the “why” or “how” to do on another way. I search for a way to call the listener, is it possible or not? I missed a method like `update` which call the listener.

Comment: Yes, you may call the listener, which in the pattern above is `YourActivity`. **Exactly, `YourActivity` = listener.** So, you may even call this listener's `onClick(View)` callback method. But what you're trying to do is to call the same callback method **indirectly**: perform a click (updateDate in your case) programmatically just to get callback method called. Does this make sense in case when you _don't think it’s a good idea to create useless calls..._?

Comment: *plonk* Today is not my day… Okay, I get it now, oh man… thanks for your patience =)