# Bad practise to call listener method manually

Tags: java, android, listener

I'm writing two listener for `EditTexts` :
One is

```
onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)
```

which implements the code to switch to the next `EditText` and enables the custom keyboard.
The second is

```
public void onClick(View v)
```

which should request the focus on the view and also enables the custom keyboard. So I could simply call the `onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)` like this

```
onFocusChange(v, true);
```

and it would do its job.

Is it bad practise to call a listener methode manually (without throwing an event) or should I write an seperate `private method` as recommended in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901708/android-call-listener-manually-from-java-code). Which practise is better/cleaner?

Comment: If I understand this correct, basically what you want is the `EditText` to have focus so that it could pop open the keyboard and move to the next field, you can call `requestFocus()` on the EditText in that case. Or your should probably use attributes in the your xml like nextFocus*(Down/Left/Right/Up) to define which `View` should get focus.!

Comment: yes, but I have to call the different methods to enable the custom keyboards. I already use the nextFocus function. That's why I put the original code into the onFocusChange-method. But if the EditText has already focus and the keyboard is hidden (manually done) I don't want to write a method only for that. I'd like to reuse the code in the first listener

Comment: In that case, Like in @lordoku 's answer, I would suggest to have a `private method` rather than invoking the `onFocusChange`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think functionally it doesn't matter. However I'd argue that a listen should follow an event, so writing a private method that does the work would probably be cleaner. For reuse, you could have the listener call this method.

Comment: ok, I will put the code into a private method and call it from the two listeners. Won't be so much work that it would be a problem to change, thanks!